SwiftUI RTL issue in search field options menu
The search field options menu, shows it content flipped in Right to left languages like Arabic, as you can see in screenshot below

the only thing I did is adding the searchable to navigation stack
.searchable(text: self.$searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
The options menu should be flipped to right edge as image below


Are you saying that the Arabic text is mirrored in the first screen shot?  It is very difficult for someone who doesn't read Arabic to understand what the issue that you are reporting is.

@Paulw11, Yes the text is mirrored, this is happens for all text fields in SwiftUI, the options menu items will be mirrored.

Sounds like a bug you should report to Apple via the feedback assistant.

@Paulw11, I did that, and waiting their response.
